# Mathematical notation for solid torus?

Tags: general-topology

Maybe a stupid question, but my googling is weak. I know the mathematical notation for a torus in 3-D is $\mathbb{T}^2$, but strictly speaking a torus is hollow, so is there a short notation for the solid torus? $S^1 \times D^2 = ?$

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, see [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solid_torus).

Comment: Sorry I don't know anything about topology, what is the short notation?

Comment: Note that $S^1\times D^1$ is an annulus, or a cylindrical shell without a top and bottom. You want $D^2$.

Comment: @1233023 You mean $S^1\times D^2$.

Comment: Actually I meant the unit disk, so $D_1$?

Comment: No $D^1$ is an interval. The superscript is its dimension.

Comment: @DietrichBurde: The article you link to doesn't mention a short notation, and in fact I'm not aware of any standard notation for it.